# mongodb not insert the full array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I use the following to insert 499 entry into a subdocument, I get the data from an array 
my code is something like this (i will shortcut the array because it too long)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var app = express();
var url = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157342.mlab.com:57342/heroku_4p9ggb81";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
 var entery = ['غبة خاتون','حي الربيع','المغرب','القاهرة','الصليخ',.........];
   var collection = db.collection('customers');
for (var i = 0 ; i<entery.length; i++){
     var query =  {"_id" : ObjectId(),"value": entery[i],"key": i}
collection.updateOne({"_id":ObjectId("59ccdf34aabdd50011258cbf")},{ "$push": { "lookupdata": query }},{ upsert: true },
    function (err, result) {if (err) throw err;db.close();
  });
      console.log(i + "- " + entery[i] + " add data finsh ");}
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function (){
    console.log("server is started");});
```

my document structure like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59cce9fcaabdd50011258cc0"),
"formorder" : 1,
"isDisplayOnList" : true,
"issystemfield" : false,
"isMandatory" : false,
"description" : "-",
"labelname" : "name",
"displayname" : "name",
"fieldtype" : "list",
"formname" : "people",
"lookupdata" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "test",
        "key" : "1",
        "id" : "669c78c9-d086-442c-954b-d6d3f861664b"
    }
],
```

}

my problem that my code does not insert all the 499 entry from the array into the "lookupdata" object, it just enters 50 entry and sometimes just 120 etc, I try to change the way I write this code many times but the problem still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting/updating the data without using a callback, use async module.

```
    `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var express = require("express");
    var path = require("path");
    var session = require('express-session');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var async = require('async');
    var app = express();
    var url = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157342.mlab.com:57342/heroku_4p9ggb81";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       if (err) throw err;
     var enteries = ['غبة خاتون','حي الربيع','المغرب','القاهرة','الصليخ',.........];
       var collection = db.collection('customers');
    async.eachOf(enteries, function(entery, key, callback){
         var query =  {"value": entery,"key": key}
    collection.updateOne({"_id":ObjectId("59ccdf34aabdd50011258cbf")},{ "$push": { "lookupdata": query }},{ upsert: true },
        function (err, result) {if (err) throw err;db.close();
      });
      }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
      });
          console.log(i + "- " + entery[i] + " add data finsh ");}
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function (){
        console.log("server is started");});`
```

Comment: First, install async module using `npm install --save async`

Comment: Billion thanks to you, now I got what I want without any problem, it will be great if you told me why we use this module or what we did here (i still not understand it).

Comment: @MhadMorph What you are doing is inserting the data which is asynchronous, and you are using for loop which will not wait for the query to save the data and loop the value, again and again, that's why you will get undesirable result sometimes it saves only 50, sometimes 120...